# Difference between terminal "sudo" and applescript "do shell script ... with administrator privileges"?

Tags: macos, applescript, admin, sudo

It seems there is a difference.

I have a C# program (.net core 3.1) fetching certificates located on flash usb drives.
I can't figure out why program launched via terminal sudo returns certificates while program launched with "do shell script ... with administrator privileges" does not.

Is this some kind of sandboxing that prevent program from reading usb devices?

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: This is another thread describing my problem I've posted. But no answers.
[.net core application with admin rights does not see usb flash drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689967/net-core-application-with-admin-rights-does-not-see-usb-flash-drives)

Comment: Please post the unix command you're using. There's no real difference between `sudo` and `do shell script ... with administrator privileges`. The usual problem in these cases is that `do shell script` uses a default PATH variable that's different from the PATH used in a terminal session. Often you have to use full paths to executables, because DSS can't find them otherwise.

Comment: @TedWrigley, I've added link to another thread describing my problem

Comment: @TedWrigley, I have the same problem described by  Steveorevo https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124185. My application does not have access to removable devices when run with  "do shell script ... with administrator privileges"